# How to access application api from oracle cloud instance?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I hava created a VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro instance from oracle cloud, and the instance is running a java applicaiton.

I want to access api from oralce cloud instance.

I have configured the Virtual cloud network's security list ingress to allow access to all IP addresses.

ping [public ip] is working.
ssh to instance is working.

But I try to curl -X GET "http:[public ip]:[port]/example/api/..." always get connection refused.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem....

instance need to run the command

`sudo systemctl enable firewalld`

`sudo systemctl start firewalld`

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent`

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp --permanent`

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=[application port]/tcp --permanent`

`sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

`sudo firewall-cmd --list-all` to check your firewall port

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access the API from another machine, ensure there are no local firewalls blocking outgoing requests. Local firewalls can sometimes interfere with the connectivity to your Oracle Cloud instance. Verify and adjust your local firewall settings to allow the necessary outbound traffic.